# If $f(x)/x$ has no limit when $x\to\infty$ then $f'(x)$ has no limit when $x\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be some continuously differentiable function on $(0, +\infty) $ such that $f(x)/x$ has no limit when $x \rightarrow +\infty$.

Prove that $f'$ has no limit at $+\infty$.

The only thing I see is that the function doesn't have horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Much simpler approaches than the ones already on the page exist, but since the OP accepted an answer as soon as they could, to post other solutions seems pointless.

Comment: @Did what are your methods?

Comment: @G.T.R Basic real analysis (in this case, the definition of limit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sketch of a solution to your problem. The advantage is that you do not need to know about L'Hopitals rule, we instead appeal directly to the mean value theorem. An important ingredient in the proof of that rule is the mean value theorem.

Assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f^\prime(x)=L$.Let  $\delta >0$. Then there is an $N$ such that  $|f^\prime(x)-L|<\delta$ for $x\geq N$. By the mean value theorem we have that  $\frac{f(x)-f(N)}{x-N}=f^\prime(\xi)$ some $\xi \in (N,x)$. Hence $|\frac{f(x)-f(N)}{x-N}-L|=|f^\prime(\xi)-L|<\delta$ if $x\geq N$   . Futhremore by choosing $x$ (even) larger we have $|(\frac{x-N}{x}-1)|<\delta$ and $|\frac{f(N)}{x-N}|<\delta$. Also note that  $|\frac{x-N}{x}|\leq 2$ for large $x$. It follows that

$$|\frac{f(x)}{x}-L|=|\frac{f(x)}{x}\frac{x-N}{x-N}-L|=$$ $$|\frac{f(x)-f(N)+f(N)}{x}\frac{x-N}{x-N}-L|=|\frac{f(x)-f(N)}{x-N}\frac{x-N}{x}-L+\frac{f(N)}{x-N}\frac{x-N}{x}|$$ $$\leq |(\frac{f(x)-f(N)}{x-N}-L)\frac{x-N}{x}+L(\frac{x-N}{x}-1)+\frac{f(N)}{x-N}\frac{x-N}{x}|$$ $$\leq|(\frac{f(x)-f(N)}{x-N}-L)||\frac{x-N}{x}|+|L||(\frac{x-N}{x}-1)|+|\frac{f(N)}{x-N}\frac{x-N}{x}|\leq$$ $$ 2\delta  +|L|\delta +2\delta $$

The last expression can be made smaller than any given $\epsilon>0$, by picking a small enough $\delta$.

Comment: 1. I didn't understand the first step on the last line: how do you substitute $x_n$ with $x_n - e$ in the denominator?  2. Aren't you supposed to prove the existence of limit of fraction before calculating its value?

Comment: I have made the answer more explicit now (hopefully).

Comment: answer to 2. Yes, but the existence of the limit follows by the existence of each of the limits in the first paragraph.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you, I really appreciated your help.

Comment: I have for example used the fact that if $\lim f(x)=A$ and $\lim g(x)=B$ then $\lim f(x)+g(x) =A+B$. Inherent in the $\lim$ -notation is the fact that the limit exists..

Comment: Yes, I've realized that. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: Your proof shows promise, but how do you know that $c_n\to\infty$? And what is the role of your $\epsilon$? I think you need to pick a small $\epsilon$, then $M$ with $x\ge M\Rightarrow|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon$, then conclude $(L-\epsilon)(x-M)\le f(x)-f(M)\le(L+\epsilon)(x-M)$. The details get a bit messier, but it is still doable.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean, I'll try to edit the answer right know.

Comment: I basically rewrote the whole answer, I hope it is better now. Thank you again for the comment..I am so frustrated that I did not see the flaw in my previous proof (really careless of me).

Answer (score 8):

*Hint*: Assume that $f'(x)$ has a limit, then use L'Hôpital.

**Edit:** To explain in (a lot) more detail, assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L$.

First, if $L>0$ then you can easily prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$: There must be some $M$ with $f'(x)>L/2$ when $x>M$. It follows that $f(x)-f(M)=\int_M^xf'(t)\,dt>(x-M)L/2$, therefore $f(x)\to\infty$. Now the requirements for using L'Hôpital are fulfilled, and you get $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L.$$

Similarly, if $L<0$ you turn some inequalities around in the above argument to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, and use L'Hôpital the same way, with the same conclusion.

Finally, if $L=0$ then applying the above to $g(x)=f(x)+x$, you get $\lim_{x\to\infty}g'(x)=1\ne0$, so $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{x}=1.$$ Subsitute in the definition of $g(x)$ and subtract $1$ to get $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0.$$

**PS.** This is a quick proof using a bit of machinery. The proof by user22705 is probably more instructive, but then it also requires more work.

Comment: As far as I understand, you suggest to prove contrapositive: existence of limit of derivative implies existence of limit of fraction, right? But to apply L'Hopital, I need to make sure that $\lim f(x) = + \infty$, right?

Comment: The limit of $f(x)$ must be $\pm\infty$ for L'Hôpital. You can easily prove that if $f'(x)$ has a nonzero limit. And if $f'(x)\to0$, you can use a simple trick: Just replace $f(x)$ by $x+f(x)$.

Comment: 1. The limit of $f(x)$ must be $+\infty$ because the denominator goes to $+ \infty$. 2. Using your trick: $\lim \frac{f(x) + x}{x} =  \lim f'(x) + 1 = 1$. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: However, I don't see how it helps to prove the statement.

Comment: Um, I think I misread your comment above. Let me amend the answer a bit to explain …

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for explanation!